# TSLint expected arrow-parameter to have a typedef

Tags: angular, typescript, typedef, tslint

I am refactoring an Angular application due to a TSLint failure which is preventing commits. The offending line was originally:

```
const safeCsvLine = allCsvLines.map(csvLine => this.getSafeCsvCells(csvLine));
```

Originally it was complaining about the safeCsvLine const, which I altered to the below. This is now passing the pre-commit:

```
const safeCsvLine: string[] = allCsvLines.map(csvLine => this.getSafeCsvCells(csvLine));
```

The problem is now in the arrow parameter. I cannot figure out the syntax for setting a tytpedef on the csvLine param. The error I am receiving is:

> expected arrow-parameter: 'csvLine' to have a typedef

The parameter is a string type. Thanks

Comment: `.map((csvLine: string) => ...)`? Or even `.map((csvLine: string): string => ...)`, to include the return type too. See the examples [in the docs](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/typedef/).

Comment: That's it! I was missing the parentheses. Thanks for the quick reply